# How to save a desktop with narrowed indirect buffers?

Tags: bookmarks, narrowing, indirect-buffers

I am unable to figure out a way to save my narrowed indirect buffer window, and restore it as it was.

Say I have a frame with several windows containing several indirect buffers, each narrowed to a different subtree (org mode) or region. What I want to achieve is to save the layout including the frame, all window, and all narrowed indirect buffers as well as their positions.

I installed `desktop+`, and used `desktop-save-mode`. Later I also used `bookmark+`, which provides commands such as `bmkp-set-desktop-bookmark`, and `bmkp-desktop-jump`. Both give unsatisfactory results when it comes to narrowed indirect buffers: The windows with indirect buffers will only show the complete file/buffer, instead of the narrowed one when I reopen and restore after `C-x C-c`.

I noticed that `bookmark+` does provide a way to save regions and late allow you to jump to an clone indirect buffer with that region (along with `narrow indirect` package installed). However, it does not provide solutions at the desktop or even file level.

It's easy if you want to reproduce the results. Set `desktop-save-mode` to `t` in your init.el. Then open a file, split the window and create a narrowed indirect buffer (the easiest way is use an org-file, and narrow to a subtree using `C-c C-x b`. Exit emacs `C-x C-c`, then reopen it. You'll see your indirect buffer shows the full copy instead of the narrowed subtree in your previous desktop.

I really appreciate if someone can help me figure it out.

Comment: OK, I moved the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bookmark+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) lets you combine multiple bookmarks as a [sequence bookmark](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#FunctionSequenceVarlistBookmarks).

You could try a sequence bookmark that first restores the desktop (using a [desktop bookmark](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#DesktopBookmarks)) and then restores a particular narrowing (using a [region bookmark](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkedRegion) and, say, `bmkp-region-jump-narrow-indirect-other-window`).